# How to solve the opposite of max flow problem?

Tags: graph-theory

Each edge in graph has a minimum bound instead of a maximum capacity.
The goal is to find the minimum flow such that every edge in graph has flow larger than it's lower bound.

I tried to use Ford fulkerson with "augmenting path": path from s to t where at least one edge in path have remaining capacity.

But this doesn't seem to provide the correct result.

Comment: Could you perhaps make your question a bit less terse?

Answer (score 4):

There is a technique for allowing both minimum and maximum capacities for each edge, where both the bounds can be positive or negative. It works by converting the network to a normal one where the edge minimum capacities are 0. Do that with the negatives of your edge capacities and maximise the negative flow.  Negating this gives you a minimum flow with the given constraints.  Sorry if this is not completely clear; you can find the method in detail in Chapter 5 of "Graph Algorithms" by Shimon Even (start at p108 in the 2nd edition).